# How do I execute a Ruby command when a link_to is pressed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

Basically, what I want to do is run a `FactoryGirl.create` whenever a `link_to` is pressed.

Right now, every time I want to generate a new object in my DB, I have to go into Rails Console and type: `FactoryGirl.create(:object)`.

But, ideally...I would love to be able to execute that from the `link_to`.

Not sure how to do that though.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you creating objects this way intentionally, rather than using Rails conventions?

Comment: This is just in a development environment. As far as I am concerned, FactoryGirl follows Rails conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could treat the creation of an object via FactoryGirl like any other RESTful resource with a dedicated controller and routes:

```
class MyFactoryGirlController

  def create
    if FactoryGirl.create(:object)
      # Do something
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
post '/someroute', to: 'myfactorygirl#create', as: :factory_girl
```

And your link:

```
link_to "Create an object", factory_girl_path(object: 'SomeObject'), method: :post
```

Note that this code is meant to illustrate a concept and is incomplete. Copy and pasting will not work.

Comment: The issue is that it doesn't access the FactoryGirl settings I have in my `spec` folder. How do I get it to access this settings?

Comment: I'm not sure how the settings are being used, nor am I altogether familiar with FactoryGirl. If the settings are stored in a hash, perhaps move them into a constant (elsewhere) and access them in both places?

Comment: I figured it out. Basically, in the controller I did `FactoryGirl.create(:object, name: Faker::Name.name, title: Faker::Lorem.word...)`. In other words, I passed the attributes I use in the FactoryGirl spec file for that factory, I just passed it to the create call in the controller. But I did it without the blocks. Works like a charm. If you update your answer to reflect that, I will accept it. Thanks!